# Get text of XML node given text of adjacent node with xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Several posts on SO have been helpful but I have not found one that answers this particular problem.

I am using python3 and lxml.etree

Given the XML:

```
<collection xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<record>
<datafield tag="856" ind1="4" ind2=" ">
<subfield code="y">English</subfield>
<subfield code="s">387115</subfield>
<subfield code="u">
http://some_url/record/1475606/files/COOLPDF-EN.pdf
</subfield>
</datafield>
</record>
</collection>
```

A collection contains several hundred records with a few dozen datafields (this is all very arcane Library of Congress stuff)

If a datafield has tag 856 and has subfield with text English I want the text of the link at node subfield code="u".

I have tried:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
ns = '{http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim}'
tree = ET.parse('example.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
eng = root.findall(
    './/{0}datafield[@tag="856"]/[{0}descendant::text="English"]/[{0}following-sibling::code="u"]'.format(ns))
print([e.text for e in eng])
```

But this just gives me an empty list.

Any help is appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your XPath.

First, you can't put a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) (`[]`) directly after a `/`.

Second, `descendant::text` is selecting a descendant element named `text` (which you don't have in your XML). Similarly, `following-sibling::code` is selecting an element named `code` and not an attribute.

Try this instead:

```
eng = root.findall('.//{0}datafield[@tag="856"][{0}subfield="English"]/{0}subfield[@code="u"]'.format(ns))
```

If you want to use more complicated XPaths, use `xpath()` instead. For example, if you wanted to only check the `subfield` element with a `code` attribute value of "y" for the text `English`, you could do (this results in an invalid predicate error using `findall()`):

```
eng = root.xpath('.//s:datafield[@tag="856"][s:subfield[@code="y"]="English"]/s:subfield[@code="u"]', namespaces=ns)
```

Also, there's nothing wrong with how you're handling the namespace but I find it easier to map prefixes to namespace uris; especially when there are multiple namespaces.

Example...

```
ns = {'s': 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim'}
eng = root.findall('.//s:datafield[@tag="856"][s:subfield="English"]/s:subfield[@code="u"]', namespaces=ns)
```